# Why onLaunch method of FCM is get called multiple times

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Every time i click on push notification it will redirect to desired screen but if I goes to homescreen where i configure fcm it will redirect to that desired screen automatically instead to stay on homescreen
[image]
Plugin used - firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
  //forNotification();
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        print("onMessage for type: ${message['notification_type']}");
        //print("onMessage for title: ${message['aps']['title']}");
        //Get.to(ServiceNotificationDetails(message['data']['notification_id']));
        /*Get.to(ServiceNotificationDetails(index, serviceNotificationList));*/
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        print("onMessage for type: ${message['data']['notification_type']}");
        moveTo(message, message['data']['notification_type']);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        print("onMessage for type: ${message['data']['notification_type']}");
      },
    );

    isFinalMethod.value = init.read("petowner");
    print("IN OR NOT ");
    tabController =
        new TabController(length: isFinalMethod.value ? 3 : 2, vsync: this);
    setImage();
  }

  void moveTo(Map<String, dynamic> message,String notification_type)async{
    print("Notification type is $notification_type");
    switch (notification_type){
      case "1":
        Get.offAll(ServiceNotificationDetails(message['data']['notification_id']));
        break;
      case "2":
        Get.offAll(PetItemDetails(0,message['data']['project_id']));
        break;
      case "3":
        Get.offAll(ServiceNotificationDetails(message['data']['notification_id']));
        break;

    }
  }

  forNotification()async{
    if (!initialized) {
      firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
      firebaseMessaging.configure();

      // For testing purposes print the Firebase Messaging token
      String token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");

      initialized = true;
    }
  }
```

Here's the code of fcm config and navigaton method.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Can you show your code snippet?

Comment: @Sisir added image

Comment: Adding the source code as in image is never a good idea. If someone wants to try out the code on their local system, they will not be able to. Better approach is to add therelevenat fumction or class code here

Comment: Added code too @Sisir